# Unable to return only nested model properties using sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I have the model `Product` and the model `Category` which have a `many to many` relashionship.I would like to get all **categories** in which a **Product** belongs.
So here what i've done:

`const product_categories=await Product.findByPk(product_id,{
            include:{
                model:Category,
                as:'categories',
            },});`

The query works just fine,but in the response i've got  first the `Product object` with the nested `Category`,but what i really want is to only display categories.Here is the result.
[image: e]

I dont want to see the `Product attributes`,i'm only intersted the nested `Category`.Or having only the `product_id value` has `key` and into it nest the `Category`.How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip the logic.

```js
const productCategories = await Category.findAll({
  attributes: ['id', 'name'], // or whatever attributes you want, remove this if you want all of them
  where: {
    productId: product_id
  },
  transaction
})
```

on the other hand, I think you can remove the product attributes while still using your approach:

```js
const product_categories = await Product.findByPk(product_id,{
  attributes: [], // <== no product attributes
  include:[{
      model:Category,
      as:'categories',
  }],
  transaction
})
```

Comment: whay should i add transaction?

Comment: Transactions are required.Just like bank transactions, if a button click triggers a whole chain of calls in the back whether in the server or between the server and the database, and for any reason, one of the calls fails, an error has to be thrown and ALL of the changes made to the database up until the call that failed have to be reverted. A rollback has to be made. If all of the calls USE THE SAME transaction (you pass it around, from a route to an endpoint to another endpoint, to an internal function and so forth) succeed, the database changes are then committed. Check the docs!